# Linked list in c displayed with same values

Tags: c, structure

I have a CSV file containing lines separated by ','

The file looks like this:

```
FIRST,00-92-93,1,0,1
SECOND,53-12-53,5,1,5
THIRD,12-33-51,5,0,51
```

Linked list looks like this:

```
struct Data{
    char *dat;
    char *uname;
    bool war_dep;
    int edu_period;
    bool dorms;
};

struct llist{
    Data d;
    llist *next;
};
```

I have a function that itterates over this file, separating each line into chunks and 
adding them to a structure.

Here's my programm:

```
void showi(llist *u){
    while(u){
        printf("Name: %s\t Date: %s\n", u->d.dat, u->d.uname);
        u=u->next;
    }
}

void inserti(llist **head, char *line){
    char *tok;
    llist *p=new llist;
    int i=0;

    tok = strtok(line, ",");
    while(tok!=NULL){
            switch(i){
            case 0:
                p->d.dat=tok;
                break;
            case 1:
                p->d.uname=tok;
                break;
            case 2:
                p->d.war_dep=atoi(tok);
                break;
            case 3:
                p->d.edu_period=atoi(tok);
                break;
            case 4:
                p->d.dorms=atoi(tok);
                break;
            }
            i++;
            tok=strtok(NULL, ",");
            }
    p->next=NULL;
    if(*head!=NULL)
        p->next=*head;
    *head=p;

    printf("Callback: %s\n", p->d.dat);
}

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    char line[128], *tok;
    llist *head;

    head = NULL;
    int i=0;
    fp=fopen("data.txt", "r");

    while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp))
    {
        inserti(&head, line);
    }
    fclose(fp);

    showi(head);

    return 0;
}
```

When above code is executed I get callbacks from **inserti** (just to make sure each line is processed properly), however when I try to display my list I got only the last value (in this case I get 3 **THIRD**). I don't know why it happens, maybe something wrong with this piece of code in **inserti**

```
p->next=NULL;
    if(*head!=NULL)
        p->next=*head;
    *head=p;
```

Comment: Probably, because the pointers from `strtok` that you store, have their data overwritten when the next line is processed. Use `strdup` and store a pointer to a *copy* of the token. `p->d.dat = strdup(tok);`

Comment: This line: `llist *p=new llist;` does not appear to be C.  Ignoring the C tag for the moment, what language are you actually using.

Comment: Yeah, 'llist *p=new llist' is from C++, but I hope it doesn't affect the code

Comment: Thank you!!!!  p->d.dat = strdup(tok);  was the issue.

Comment: Well, `new` is defined as a keyword in C++, but not in C.  It might affect your code.

Comment: Also, in C, I think your reference to `Data d;` in `struct llist` needs to be `struct Data d;`.  Same with all references to `llist`.  Or, you can `typedef` them to avoid prefacing them with `struct`.

Answer (score 1):

You are storing the token pointers in the struct, but when you read the next line the data is overwritten. That is why the last line's data appears in all the records.

You should make a copy of each token, such as with

```
p->d.dat = strdup(tok);
```

and similar for other members. Don't forget to `free` those pointers later, as `strdup` uses `malloc` internally.

Answer (score 1):

When you copy over the first two fields:

```
p->d.dat=tok;
...
p->d.uname=tok;
```

You're actually copying a *pointer* to a position in the `line` array.  This is the same `line` from main which gets overwritten each time.

You want to make a copy of each of those strings to put in your struct.  You can do that and allocate the space for them at the same time using `strdup`:

```
p->d.dat=strdup(tok);
...
p->d.uname=strdup(tok);
```

When you clean up your list, make sure to `free` these fields in each node before calling `free` on the node.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `fgets` with `line` data is stored into `line`. `line` is then passed to `inserti`, which uses `strtok` to locate the data you want from the line. `tok` is a pointer to a character in `line`, which is then stored in your linked list node `p`. When the next line is read `line` is updated and all of those pointers in `p` are now pointing to the updated line. What you need to do is allocate a new string for the individual members of `p` or else allocate a new buffer for `line` every time a line is read. Try using `strdup(tok)` instead of assigning members of `p` to `tok` directly.

Answer (score 0):

```
p->d.dat = strdup(tok);
```

This helped me!
I've made some minor adjustments by changing `p->d.dat = tok;` `to p->d.dat = strdup(tok);`

`inserti` now looks like this:

```
void inserti(llist **head, char *line){
    char *tok;
    llist *p=new llist;
    int i=0;

    tok = strtok(line, ",");
    while(tok!=NULL){
            switch(i){
            case 0:
                p->d.dat=strdup(tok);
                break;
            case 1:
                p->d.uname=strdup(tok);
                break;
            case 2:
                p->d.war_dep=atoi(tok);
                break;
            case 3:
                p->d.edu_period=atoi(tok);
                break;
            case 4:
                p->d.dorms=atoi(tok);
                break;
            }
            i++;
            tok=strtok(NULL, ",");
            }
    p->next=NULL;
    if(*head!=NULL)
        p->next=*head;
    *head=p;

    printf("Callback: %s\n", p->d.dat);
}
```

Comment: Again,  You are using the `new` C++ keyword.  This is _not_ compiling in C.  Change your tags to remove `C`, and add `C++`.

Comment: I got it. @ryyker I've changed it to    **struct llist* p=(llist*)malloc(sizeof(struct llist));** I mean, now it looks like C

Comment: Maybe you could update your post(s) to reflect that change.